# AWS - Calling Google Calendar API, Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-calendar-api

I am having issues trying to create a calendar event using the Google Calendar API with an AWS Lambda function call.

The AWS CloudWatch logs are not giving me a whole lot of information to work with for debugging. I am very new to working with the Google API and can't figure out what is going wrong with my code.

The code I am using is here:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from oauth2client import service_account
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

import httplib2
import boto3
import json
import logging
import requests


def lambda_handler(event, context):
  logger = logging.getLogger()
  logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

  ses = boto3.client('ses')
  email_address = 'myemail@gmail.com'  # change it to your email address

  SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'aws-iot-f3edea2d0394.json'

  credentials = service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
          SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)
  service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

  calendarId = 'myemail@gmail.com'

  event = {
    "summary": "aws iot test",
    "location": "etc",
    "description": "aws iot test - pushed from button",
    "start": {
      "dateTime": "2018-01-31T09:00:00-07:00",
      "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    "end": {
      "dateTime": "2018-01-31T17:00:00-07:00",
      "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    }
  }

  event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
```

The calendar event is not being created, and I cannot figure out why. The only information I am getting from the AWS CloudWatch logs has the last event here:

```
[INFO]  2018-01-23T17:09:28.116Z    29b2e36a-0060-11e8-8c9e-1725945b009e    URL being requested: POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json
```

This is not very informative. Can anyone help out with maybe getting AWS to give me more information, or perhaps point out what I am doing wrong in the Python code? Thank you!

Comment: I try the same, and got an error: 
An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?sendUpdates=all&alt=json returned "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.". Details: "[{'domain': 'calendar', 'reason': 'forbiddenForServiceAccounts', 'message': 'Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.'}]"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue. Google left out some administrative details needed for the integration to work, and I was able to track down a similar issue someone else was having at [Google Calendar Api v3 asp.net Code 200, yet no event inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313376/google-calendar-api-v3-asp-net-code-200-yet-no-event-inserted).

Turns out you need to enable the Google service account to make changes to your calendar.